# Is countable sum of finite-dimensional subspaces finite-dimensional?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space. Let $\mathcal{S}=\{Y_1, Y_2,...\}$ be a countable family of finite-dimensional subspaces of $X$ partially ordered by inclusion.  Is
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}Y_i$$ 
finite dimensional?

Comment: I don't understand, if you take any infinite dimensional vector space, then you have a basis for it by the axiom of choice, and thus a countable (infinite) linearly independant family of vectors say $x_1,...,x_n,..$. Then $V_n=(x_1,...,x_n)$ satisfies your condition, and the unions of the $V_i$'s won't be finite dimensionnal.
Or I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Can we use Zorn-Kuratowski lemma to deduce there exists maximal finite-dimensional subspace of $X$?

Comment: No. If you have a finite dimensional subspace included in an infinite dimensional space, then you can always add a linearly independent vector from the infinite dimensional space , so there cannot exist a maximal finite dimensional subspace.

Comment: Well... no, as if $V$ is such a maximal finite dimensional space, then either it is $X$, but then $X$ is finite dimensionnal, which may well be the case, but I mean this is rather an uninterresting case. Or it is not $X$ but then take $x$ not in $V$ then $V\oplus \mathbb{R}x$ is stricly larger than $V$ and contains $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=l^{2}$ and $Y_n$ be the finite dimensional space spanned by $e_1,e_2,..,e_n$. Then $\cup Y_i$ is not finite dimensional. However it is of interest to note that if $Y_i$'s are as specified and  $X=\cup_i Y_i$ then $X$ is finite dimensional. (TH his is a consequence of Baire Category Theorem).

Comment: For this application of Baire's theorem, it is enough to assume that $\bigcup_i Y_i$ is closed.

Comment: I feel like a detail is omitted here. I don't follow the logic of the last bit at all.

Comment: I did not elaborate on the last part because it was not part of the question I was answering. I just mentioned it because it was an interesting point related to the question.

Comment: If it's a half answer that someone with years of experience can't follow, it might not be worth including at all.

Comment: $Cameron Williams The OP has no objection to my comment and gerw liked and improved it my comments. Could you post my comment as a new question so that I or someone else can post a detailed answer?